# How to get a SVG's aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

Is there a way to get a loaded svg's aspect ratio? I want to be able to know the scaling that goes into the `preserveAspectRatio` property. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) states that for `meet`:

- aspect ratio is preserved
- the entire viewBox is visible within the viewport
- the viewBox is scaled up as much as possible, while still meeting the other 
  criteria

Is there a way to retrieve the aspect ratio that the property somehow knows in JS?

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example of the html/js code you're developing? See [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - "Help others reproduce the problem" section. Otherwise many things are not that clear. I guess that stopped people from answering. For example, what is mean under "svg" in the question? Is that an SVG tag? Or an image in svg format loaded via <img> tag. Or something else? So context would be great.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was able to find my answer here which is essentially the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798288/retrieving-the-aspect-ratio-of-an-svg-image

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [*"retrieving the aspect ratio of an svg <image>"*](/q/29798288) and should have not been closed as such. This question is about the aspect ratio of an SVG determined by its viewBox attribute, whereas the linked to question is about the dimensions / aspect ratio of an `<image>` element within an SVG. These are completely different issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's fairly easy to get the viewBox's values like described in Phrogz' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7682976/4235784) to [*"Obtaining an original SVG viewBox via javascript"*](/q/7676006):

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var box = svg.viewBox.baseVal;
```

Getting the aspect ratio from that requires just simple math:

```
var aspectRatio = box.width / box.height;
```

Comment: This is not correct. The aspect ratio is just `box.width / box.height`.